Sufficiency for Pareto distribution
Let $X_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$ be i.i.d. Pareto (type 1) random variables with scale $\alpha > 0$ and shape $\beta > 2$. The density is given by
$$
f(x; \theta) = \beta \alpha^{\beta} x^{-(\beta + 1)} \mathbb{I}_{[\alpha, \infty)}(x)
$$
or equivalently,
$$
f(x; \theta) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x < \alpha, \\
\beta \alpha^{\beta} x^{-(\beta + 1)}, & \text{if } x \geq \alpha.
\end{cases}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$  and  $\theta = (\alpha, \beta)'$.

Problem:
Show that the statistic $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is not sufficient for $\beta$ if $\alpha = \beta$.

My Work:
I found that the joint density is equal to:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n} \beta^{\beta + 1} \cdot x_i^{-(\beta + 1)} \mathbb{I}_{[\beta, \infty)}(x).
$$
I tried to check whether the ratio of two samples is independent of $\beta$, but this did not provide much clarity. I obtained:
$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\beta^{\beta + 1} x_i^{-(\beta + 1)}\mathbb{I}_{[\beta, \infty)}(x)}{\beta^{\beta + 1} y_i^{-(\beta + 1)}\mathbb{I}(y)}$
I do not see why $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is not sufficient, as if $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \prod_{i=1}^{n} y_i$, won’t the ratio be independent of the parameter? My feeling is that it has something to do with the indicator function, which is dependent on the parameter, but I can't quite see it yet.
If someone could explain this to me or provide some intuition, I would really appreciate it since I feel stuck.

Take a look at this problem:
Find a sufficient statistic for this parameter of a Pareto distibution
The sufficient statistic for $\beta$ is $(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i)$ and $(\min_i x_i )$ is sufficient statistics for $\alpha$.
Therefore, even if $\beta=\alpha$ the sufficient statistic needs the second part $(\min_i x_i)$.

I see, thanks for that. Can you provide some intuition as to why that is? I understand that if those are the same I can just cancel min x and y out, but given that it is an indicator function wouldn't it just equate to 1 if y and x are in the specified interval?

Yes, but saying that $x$ and $y$ values are in the given interval needs to be explicitly specified, so just the product of values is not sufficient for $\beta$.

Ah, I think I get it now. In order for the parameters to cancel out (since the indicator depends on the parameter), I also need to know, explicitly that $x$ and $y$ are the same. Which explains why both $\min x_i$ and (\prod _{i=1}^n x_i) are necessary to find a sufficient statistic. Thanks for your help!

@Triangluzx  Perhaps you could accept the answer :))
